# Cannot install libmozjs185 on rpi 3 running Ubuntu Mate

Tags: pi-3b+, software-installation, ubuntu

I am looking forward to install CouchDB on my rpi 3, running Ubuntu 20.04.

However, I can not figure out how to install one of its required dependencies: libmozjs185.

I have tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y libmozjs185-1.0 libmozjs185-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libmozjs185-1.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libmozjs185-1.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libmozjs185-1.0'
E: Unable to locate package libmozjs185-dev
```

Perhaps I should compile libmozjs185, but I would prefer installing a build. If that is not possible I want to follow the right steps to compile and install it.

How can I install libmozjs185 on my pi3 running Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53769223/how-to-install-libmozjs185-dev-in-bionic

Comment: @Swedgin I don't think that the `amd64` build will work on the raspberry pi...

Comment: @Swedgin I get `package architecture (amd64) does not match system (armhf)`...

Comment: And if you change to links to `armhf`? https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+package/libmozjs185-1.0 shows a published version for `armhf`

Comment: @Swedgin I used pkgs.org to search the packages and installed the arm builds and their dependencies. Also, I posted an answer. I hope it will help others.

Comment: Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had to search the armhf (I used [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/) for this) builds of these dependencies, but note that `libmozjs185-dev` depends on `libmozjs185-1.0` which depends on `libffi6`.

```
# Download libffi6
wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libf/libffi/libffi6_3.2.1-6_armhf.deb

# Download the libmozjs185-1.0
wget http://ftp.ro.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mozjs/libmozjs185-1.0_1.8.5-1.0.0+dfsg-6_armhf.deb

# Download the libmozjs185-dev
wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mozjs/libmozjs185-dev_1.8.5-1.0.0+dfsg-6_armhf.deb


# Install libffi6
sudo dpkg -i libffi6_3.2.1-6_armhf.deb 

# Install libmozjs185-1.0
sudo dpkg -i libmozjs185-1.0_1.8.5-1.0.0+dfsg-6_armhf.deb 

# Install libmozjs185-dev
sudo dpkg -i libmozjs185-dev_1.8.5-1.0.0+dfsg-6_armhf.deb 

# Fix eventual missing dependencies
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.